# How to make 5509.099999999999 as 5509.09 using javascript

Tags: javascript

How to make 5509.099999999999 as 5509.09 using javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lots of mathy options that end up with .1 so how about;

```
var f = 5509.099999999999

if ((f = f.toString()).indexOf(".") >= 0)
    f = f.substr(0, 3 + f.indexOf("."))

print(parseFloat(f))

>>5509.09
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this?

```
var value = 5509.099999999999;
var str = value.toString();
var result = str.substr(0,7);
```

Then if you need it to be a float again you can do:

```
var FinalAnswer = parseFloat(result);
```

You don't need all these variables, but that is the step by step.

Comment: (5509.099999999999).toString().substr(0,7) simple and works like a charm, well done!

Answer (score 0):

You can truncate the number to a certain number of decimal places using this function:

```
function truncateNumber(number, digits){
 var divisor = Math.pow(10,digits);
 return Math.floor(number*divisor)/divisor;
}
```

If you want to round the number instead, you can use JavaScript's built in `Number.toFixed` function. If you always want the number a certain number of digits long, you can use the `Number.toPrecision` function.

Comment: Wasn't my downvote, but your solution still gives `5509.1` when 2 decimal places are specified.  You also have a typo ("nuber")

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.toFixed(2)` but this will round the value, so in your example you'll end up with `5509.10` instead of `5509.09`.

The next best option is to use `Math.floor()`, which truncates rather than rounding. Unfortunately, this only gives integer results, so to get the result to 2 decimal places, you'd need to multiply by 100, then use `Math.floor()`, and then divide by 100 again.

```
var value = 5509.099999999999;
var result = Math.floor(value*100)/100;
```

[EDIT]
Hmm, unfortunately, the above doesn't work due to problems with floating point precision -- even just the first step of multiplying it by 100 gives `550910`.

Which means that the best answer is likely to be converting it to a string and chopping the string into bits.

```
var value = 5509.099999999999;
var str_value = value.toString();
var bits = str_value.split('.');
var result = bits[0]+"."+bits[1].substr(0,2);
```

I wouldn't normally suggest doing string manipulation for this sort of thing, because it is obviously a maths problem, but given the specific requirements of the question, it does seem that this is the only workable solution in this case.

Comment: ah, it *should* be .09, but you're hitting a problem with floating point maths precision.  :-(  simply doing `value*100` gives `550110`. You may find the only answer that works involves `toString()` and chopping the string. I'll edit the answer....

Comment: I suspect that's the best approach in this case.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to take two decimal places, you can use `.toPrecision(n)` javascript function, where n is the **total** number of digits desired.

so, for your example, you'd have to do

```
var x = 5509.099999999999;
x = x.toPrecision(6);
```

this, however, rounds results in 5509.10

Comment: actually, this also rounds it, at least in IE8 :(

Answer (score 0):

```
   var result = (Math.round((5509.09999 * 100) - 1)) / 100;
```